# exchange elements cause wrong getposition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to exchange the position of two texts with an onclick event, also show me an alert with the position clicked (thanks user Kiran Reddy for your code). I do that, but when i change the position text, also change the position clicked alert. I don´t know what happen, any idea?
For example:

> text 1 
>   text 2
>   text 3 
>   text 4 //click here show me alert (3) that is its position, after that exchange the position an this is the result:
>
> text 1
>   text 2
>   text 4
>   text 3 //click here show me alert (2) that is wrong, its position is 3

This is my code, works in local in web doesn´t work

https://jsfiddle.net/xkg9fts9/1/

```js
arrayOffsetTop =[];

function getPosition(object)
    {
   
    var list=document.getElementsByClassName("position");
       list = [].slice.call(list);
    alert(list.indexOf(object));  
       
    }
 
function changePosition(object)
{
  //alert with the position selected
  getPosition(object); 
 
  //store offsetTop of elements in array
  if(arrayOffsetTop.length==0)
  {
  for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName("position").length;i++)
   {
   arrayOffsetTop.push(document.getElementsByClassName("position").item(i).offsetTop);
     }
  }
 //change the elements position 
 
 document.getElementsByClassName("position").item(2).style.top=arrayOffsetTop[3];
 document.getElementsByClassName("position").item(3).style.top=arrayOffsetTop[2];
 
}
```

```css
.position{
position:absolute;
}
```

```html
 
    <span   class="position" onclick= changePosition(this);     > text 1 </span><br> 
<span   class="position" onclick= changePosition(this);     > text 2 </span><br>
<span   class="position" onclick= changePosition(this);     > text 3 </span><br>  
<span   class="position" onclick= changePosition(this);     > text 4 </span><br>
```

Comment: Something like that maybe: https://jsfiddle.net/xkg9fts9/3/ unless you really want to do it by style.top.

Comment: Yes Lain, works! but what i want to know is why the getposition change?
I want that the getPosition hold, but when i change the text position change the position too ;(

Comment: In my example you do not change the style.top yet the element position itself. The element that was the second thild before becomes the third child after. That is why the getPosition of it changes. If you just want to know the original position you could do this: https://jsfiddle.net/xkg9fts9/4/